# Falta tradução do datepicker

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Fui no perfil, em visitas -> visitados, quando se clica nos dias aparece um datepicker do jqueryUI e esse esta faltando tradução.

Segue um print da tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]